# Problem with graphql with NestJS and TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am learning NestJS with TypeORM.

Here is my code resolver.ts

```
@Query(returns => LessonType)
  lesson(
    @Args('id') id: string,
  ) {
    return this.lessonService.getLesson(id);
  }
```

And my code service.ts

```
async getLesson(id: string): Promise<Lesson> {
    return this.lessonRepository.findOne({ id });
  }
```

And here is the error.
[image]

I think the error come from service.ts but I don't know how to fix it. Please teach me how to fix. Thank for your attention.

Comment: As far as I can see it's a *MongoDB* error.
In ```service.ts``` can you try to ```log``` or surround it with ```try``` and ```catch``` to *debug* and obtain some more information.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6434) issue

Comment: Thank for your help, I finally fix it, I deleted DB and created it again